# How to create a transformable grid UI on Flutter for mobile?

Tags: user-interface, flutter

What is the name of this UI below?

How do I create one in Flutter?

These are the desired characteristics:

- The scalability of the grid must have max and min values.
- Pinch to zoom function.
- Elements or vector properties should be able to snap to the grid.

Is there a library that can serve this function?

Thank you for your help!

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [transformable](https://pub.dev/packages/transformable#-readme-tab-) package found on [pub.dev](https://pub.dev/). See the example lib.dart file in the [Github example folder](https://github.com/mtcliatt/Transformable/tree/master/example/lib).

A code snippet from the pud.dev page:

```
LayoutBuilder(
  builder: (context, constraints) => Transformable(
    child: Grid(),
    viewerSize: viewerSize,
    controller: TransformController(
      config: TransformConfig(
        initialTransform: Transformation(offset: startOffset),
        initialSize: childStartSize,
        innerBoundRect: innerRect,
        outerBoundRect: outerRect,
      ),
    ),
  );
```